# Struggling programming TicTacToe in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, while-loop, stack

I'm new to C and programming and I tried to code a simple TicTacToe game. I new that I defintaly did many dumb things.

So I have a main .c file and two header files, which I will post here:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "game.h"
#include "random.h"

#define NAMELENGTH 20

int main(void) {
char names[2][NAMELENGTH];
// field positions
char field[9];
int winner = -2;
getnames(names);
printf("\n\n");
initField(field);
// set field positions to 'empty'
char actualPlayer = (char)(get_random_number()*10.0) % 2;

while (1) {
    drawField(field);
    turn(actualPlayer, names, field);
    winner = isWinner(actualPlayer, field);
    drawField(field);
    if (winner >= 0) {
        printwinner(winner, names);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (winner == -1) {
        printDrawGame(names);
        return 0;
    }
    actualPlayer = (actualPlayer + 1) % 2;
    system("cls");
}
return 0;

}
```

game.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NAMELENGTH 20
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

void drawField(char *field) {

printf("________________________\n");
printf("|       |       |      |\n");
printf("|   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[1], field[2], field[3]);
printf("|_______|_______|______|\n");
printf("|       |       |      |\n");
printf("|   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[4], field[5], field[6]);
printf("|_______|_______|______|\n");
printf("|       |       |      |\n");
printf("|   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[7], field[8], field[9]);
printf("|_______|_______|______|\n");

}

void getnames(char nameField[][NAMELENGTH]) {

printf("Name of the first player: ");
scanf("%s", &nameField[0]);
printf("Name of the second player: ");
scanf("%s", &nameField[1]);

}

void initField(char *field) {

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    field[i] = i+48;
}

}

void turn(char actualPlayer, char names[][NAMELENGTH], char *field) {

char symbol = ' ';
int k;
int m;

if (actualPlayer == 1)
{
    do {

        printf("\nIts Player %s's turn.", names[0]);
        char symbol = 'X';
        printf("\nNumber of the field which you want to put your symbol in: ");
        scanf("%i", &k);
        if (field[k] == 'X' || field[k] == 'O')
        {
            printf("\nField is already occupied!");
            k = 10;
        }
    } while (k < 1 || k > 9);
    field[k] = 'X';
}
else {

    do {
        printf("\nIts Player %s's turn.", names[1]);
        char symbol = 'O';
        printf("\nNumber of the field which you want to put your symbol in: ");
        scanf("%i", &m);
        if (field[m] == 'X' || field[m] == 'O')
        {
            printf("\nField is already occupied!");
            m = 10;
        } 
    } while (m < 1 || m > 9);

    field[m] = 'X';
}

}

 int isWinner(char actualPlayer, char *field) {

int w = 2;

if (((field[1] = 'O') && (field[2] = '0') && (field[3] = '0')) || (field[4] = '0') && (field[5] = '0') && (field[6] = '0') || (field[7] = '0') && (field[8] = '0') && (field[9] = '0') || (field[1] = '0') && (field[5] = '0') && (field[9] = '0') || (field[3] = '0') && (field[5] = '0') && (field[7] = '0') || (field[1] = '0') && (field[4] = '0') && (field[7] = '0') || (field[2] = '0') && (field[5] = '0') && (field[8] = '0') || (field[3] = '0') && (field[6] = '0') && (field[9] = '0'))

{
    int w = 1;
}

if (((field[1] = 'X') && (field[2] = 'X') && (field[3] = 'X')) || (field[4] = 'X') && (field[5] = 'X') && (field[6] = 'X') || (field[7] = 'X') && (field[8] = 'X') && (field[9] = 'X') || (field[1] = 'X') && (field[5] = 'X') && (field[9] = 'X') || (field[3] = 'X') && (field[5] = 'X') && (field[7] = 'X') || (field[1] = 'X') && (field[4] = 'X') && (field[7] = 'X') || (field[2] = 'X') && (field[5] = 'X') && (field[8] = 'X') || (field[3] = 'X') && (field[6] = 'X') && (field[9] = 'X'))

{
    int w = 0;
}

else
{
    int w = -1;
}

return w;
}

void printwinner(char winnerNumber, char names[][NAMELENGTH]) {

if (winnerNumber == 0)
{
    printf("Player %s won!", names[0]);
    system("exit");
}
else if (winnerNumber == 1)
{
    printf("Player %s won!", names[1]);
    system("exit");
}

}

void printDrawGame(char names[][NAMELENGTH]) {

printf("Draw!");
system("exit");

}
```

and random.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int _initialized;

void init() {

srand(time(NULL));
_initialized = 1;
}

double get_random_number() {

init();
if (!_initialized)
    printf("Warning: init() should be called first!\n");

double random;
random = (double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX)+1);
return random;

}
```

So the Program itself runs till I type in which field I want to put in the symbol. I get a weird error ("Stack around the variable 'field' was corrupted.") and also the random function doesnt work like I want. Would be happy and thankful for you help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `field` to be an array of 9 elements.  The indices will be 0 to 8.  In `game.h` you have a function `initField` in which you do:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    field[i] = i+48;
}
```

This will produce indices 1 to 9, which steps out of bounds for the array.

Answer (score 1):

You reinitialize the random number generator each time it is called.  You pseudo random values will not be very random I'm afraid.

Fix it this way:

```
static int _initialized;

double get_random_number() {
    if (!_initialized) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        _initialized = 1;
    }
    return = (double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX)+1);
}
```

You should not write code in header files.  Declarations belong in header files, code belongs in source files with the extension `.c`.

Comment: thx that also helped me - sry but i can only mark 1 answer as the right answer :/